# HTTP calls depending on another request in the same component Angular + repeated query

Tags: angular

I have an angular application that read from a config file the backend URL in order to process the queries. The advantage of this is that the back and front can be deployed on any servers.

In my angular application I read a JSON containing the following information:

```
{
  baseUrl: "http://server-url:8080/backend
}
```

In a service I implemented a method that open the json in the service layer:

```
getJsonConfig() {
  let jsonUrl = './assets/configuration/config.json';
  return this.http.get<any>(jsonUrl)
    .pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        this.baseUrl = response.baseUrl;
      })
    );
}
```

I have to call 2 other HTTP entry points to display data on my component: the call of those 2 URL depend on the baseUrl retrieved. First I have to retrieve a database name with this call:

```
getDbName(): Observable<getDbName> {
  const url = this.baseUrl + "/dbInfos"
  return this.http.get<getDbName>(url);
}

getData(): Observable<data[]> {
  let url = this.baseUrl + "/actions"
  return this.http.get<data[]>(url);
}
```

Here it comes more complex: I have 2 components: a parent component and a child component.
the method getData must be updated every 10 seconds because it is used to display a graph...

In the parent component, I used ngOnInit webhook to call the webservice

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.httpService.getJsonConfig().subscribe({
    next: res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.jsonConfigObject = res;
    },
    error: err => {
      this.loading = false;
      Utils.handleErrorMessage(err, this.messageService);
    },
    complete: () => {
      this.getData();
      this.getDbName();
    }
  });
}
```

At this stage, I wait the configuration to be loaded to call the 2 other webservices. Here is the implementation of those 2 methods:

```
private getDbName() {
  this.httpService.getDbName().subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        if(res != undefined) {
          this.isPathLoaded = true
        }
        this.dbName = res.path;
        return res.path;
      },
    error: err => {
      this.loading = false;
      Utils.handleErrorMessage(err, this.messageService);
    }
  });
}

private getData() {
  this.subscribe = timer(0, 10000).pipe(
    tap((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    }),
    takeUntil(this.unsub),
    switchMap(() => this.httpService.getData().pipe(
      tap({
        next: (res) => {
          if(res.length >= 1) {
            this.isDataLoaded = true
          }
          this.data = res;
        }
      }),
    ))
  ).subscribe();
}
```

I have some data to display in the parent component and for this I check i do have values before inserting the data. Here is how i handle this:

```
<div class="card" *ngIf="data">
  <p class="card-category">
     Database : {{ dbName }} <br />
     Id : {{ histData.id }} <br />
  </p>
</div>
```

After in my code I use primeng where I bind the data to the select and labels have the id as value.

```
<p-dropdown
    [options]="data"
    [(ngModel)]="histData"
    optionLabel ="id">
</p-dropdown>
```

And finally I send data to the child component:

```
<app-stacked-charts [data] = "histData" ></app-stacked-charts>
```

My issues are the following:

1. I have an error message : ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: 'someCurrentValue'
2. When i select a value in my dropdown select, In certain cases, after a few seconds, the select is returning to its default value instead of remaining on the selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some comments regarding your implementation.

First of all, you need to use [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) injection token to load configuration data to you application. It will increase initial boot-up time, but it will simplify your life.

Second, [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) operator shall be used to make subsequent dependant requests, ie in this case

```
getData(): Data {
    return this.getDbName().pipe(
        switchMap(dbName => this.getData(dbName))
    )
}
```

As soon as subscribe to getData() method, first getDbName and then data will be retrieved

Thirdly, you use [async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe to subscribe inside the template, then you don't need to handle subscriptions whatsoever

```
<div class="card" *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
  <p class="card-category">
     Database : {{ dbName }} <br />
     Id : {{ histData.id }} <br />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: the APP_INITIALIZER helped me a lot to solve the whole issue ! thanks

Comment: I implemented the APP INITIALIZER in another project... i completelly forgot about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me add some concerns to Timothys answer. Some may have influence on your issues:

- You are not unsubscribing from `getDbName` subscription
- In `getData` your `takeUntil`comes before the subsequent `switchMap`([read further](https://ncjamieson.com/avoiding-takeuntil-leaks/))
- In `getJsonConfig` your `map` doesn't return anything. You are mapping to *void*. Change to `tap` here. In `getData`you return a value in a `tap`, which is just useless. `tap` doesn't alter the streamed value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Timothy and @MoxxiManagarm, my code was a little messy. Here is how i solved my issues:

First, I created a service class:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfigService {
  private appConfig: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  loadAppConfig(): Observable<any> {
    let jsonUrl = './assets/configuration/config.json';
    return this.http.get<any>(jsonUrl)
      .pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
          this.appConfig = response;
        })
      );
  }

  getConfig(): any {
    return this.appConfig;
  }
}
```

In the app.module.ts file, i added the call to the service:

```
const appInitializer = (appConfig: AppConfigService) => {
  return () => {
    // console.log('App Initialization');
    return appConfig.loadAppConfig();
  };
};
```

I also add providers:

```
providers: [
  HttpService,
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: appInitializer,
    multi: true,
    deps: [AppConfigService]
  },
],
```

I can call directly in my component the other Http URLs. I still had at this stage the same issue. I solved it by getting data a first time before refresh the call to the backend

I updated the getData method in my component

```
getData() {
   this.dataSubscription = this.httpService.getData().subscribe({
    next: (res) => {
      this.data = res;
      this.histData = res[0];
      console.log(this.histData);
    },
    error: (err) => {
      this.loading = false;
      Utils.handleErrorMessage(err, this.messageService);
    }
  });
  this.refreshData();
}
```

And my refreshData:

```
private refreshData() {
  this.subscribe = timer(0, 10000).pipe(
    tap((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    }),
    takeUntil(this.unsub),
    switchMap(() => this.httpService.getData().pipe(
      tap({
        next: (res) => {
          this.data = res
          return res;
        }
      }),
    ))
  ).subscribe();
}
```